# Como resolver problema de tipo em formulário?

Tags: typescript

Estou criando um site de finanças e quando envio o form no devtools o campo "valor" mostra que recebe NaN e o campo "referente a" mostra como [htmlinputelement]. Como posso resolver isso?

```js
public addValues(): Obj[] | (undefined & void) {

        let inputValue = String(document.getElementById('valor'));

        let inputNameValue = String(document.getElementById('nome-valor'));

        let enterChecked = document.getElementById('entrada') as HTMLFormElement;
        let leftChecked = document.getElementById('saida') as HTMLFormElement;

        if (!inputValue || !inputNameValue.length || (enterChecked.checked === false && leftChecked.checked === false)) {
            alert('Preencha todos os campos para continuar.') 
            return undefined
            }
            const list: Obj = {
                valor: this.normalizeNumbers(+inputValue),
                nomeValor: String(inputNameValue),
                checked: enterChecked.checked ? '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>' : leftChecked.checked ? '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>' : undefined
        }
        inputValue = ''
        inputNameValue = ''
        if (enterChecked.checked) enterChecked.checked = false
        else if (leftChecked.checked) leftChecked.checked = false
        this.valores = [list]
        console.log(this.valores)
        this.createList(this.valores)
        return this.valores
    }
```

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaPPZ.png)

Comment: let inputValue = String(document.getElementById('valor'));
Você está pegando o elemento, e transformando em um string... Deve pegar o valor.

valor: this.normalizeNumbers(+inputValue)
Aqui você "converte" a string para number(de forma errônea e preguiçosa). Se precisa do valor, ele deve ser OU string OU number (no seu caso, claro, pois em outros, poderiam ser outros tipos). Imagine ficar verificando o tipo cada vez que for utilizar esse valor...

Comment: Já resolvi esse a um tempo, mas obrigado mesmo assim (com exceção do "preguiçoso").